# Curl: no URL Specified (Even though there is a URL)

Tags: system-installation

[image]

As seen in the image I am using the curl command appropriately with URL but still there is an error. **What is the issue?**

I am following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@petrstepanov/install-cern-root-roofit-on-macos-and-linux-for-dummies-df787fd41ef4

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have substituted `-o` (lower case) in place of `-O` (upper case), causing the URL to be interpreted as the name of an output file. From `man curl`:

```
   -o, --output <file>
          Write  output  to  <file> instead of stdout.
```

versus

```
   -O, --remote-name
          Write output to a local file named like the remote file we get.
```

Answer (score 1):

The -o (small alphabet o) is used to output to a file.
When you use this option curl uses the next argument as the name of file and expects another argument for the URL.

The tutorial that you have mentioned uses the -O (capital alphabet O) option.
You can learn more about these by running

```
curl --help
```